# How do I echo the dns_name's string from the ansible elb_application_lb_facts module?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, ansible, jinja2

I have part of a JSON object below in my debug which I got via `elb_application_lb_facts` module. How do I echo the dns_name's string from the object below ?

I can get narrow the output to load_balancers using this JINJA2 `{{msg.load_balancers}}`

Complete msg JSON object:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "load_balancers": [
            {
                "access_logs_s3_enabled": "true",
                "availability_zones": [
                    {
                        "subnet_id": "xyz",
                        "zone_name": "xyz"
                    },
                    {
                        "subnet_id": "xyz",
                        "zone_name": "xyz"
                    }
                ],
                "canonical_hosted_zone_id": "xyz",
                "created_time": "2017-11-15T10:54:27.230000+00:00",
                "deletion_protection_enabled": "true",
                "dns_name": "myelb.elb.amazonaws.com",
```

Comment: What do you want to get in case there are multiple load balancers?

Comment: This is an output of supplying one AWS Loadbalancer ARN to the facts module. Incase there are multiple Loadbalancer ARNs supplied then a list of dns_name would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a string with the value of the first element:

```
{{ msg.load_balancers[0].dns_name }}"
```

For a ist:

```
{{ msg.load_balancers | map (attribute='dns_name') | list }}"
```